# Correctly link Azure Devops Organisation to Azure AD Account

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I've had a standalone Azure Devops Organisation (call it MyOrg1) for quite a while, and I've recently linked it to my Azure Active Directory, and set my Azure AD user myname@my-azure-ad as the organisation owner.

This seemed to work ok. I can go directly to the URL dev.azure.com/MyOrg1, and see all my projects etc. All good so far.

The problem is that if instead I go directly to dev.azure.com, and login as my Azure AD user, it doesn't seem to recognise that this user is already associated with an existing devops account. It instead prompts me with the "Get started with Azure DevOps" screen with the option to "Continue".

If I choose "Continue" it then creates a new Organization for me like "[myname]1234".

So far this is mostly just a nuisance, but not a huge problem. However the more significant problem is that in Visual Studio, I'm not able to see MyOrg1. It will only list the new organisation "[myname]1234". If I attempt to manually add the server URL "dev.azure.com/MyOrg1" it won't work, and doesn't seem to recognise that the user myname@my-azure-ad has access to this organisation.

It shows the message "To access an Azure DevOps account, login using the picker above". The picker already shows my user myname@my-azure-ad

In the MyOrg1 organization settings, I can see that my account is definitely listed as the organisation owner, and I can see that my Azure AD is definitely linked.

I can't figure out what could be wrong. Everything looks correct, but it just doesn't work.

Just in case it makes a difference, organisation MyOrg1 is in a different region to my Azure AD. I can't really see why that would matter though, since it seemed to link it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to correct the issue by doing the following...

1. Create a new Global Admin user account in AAD
2. Add this user to the DevOps organisation and set as owner
3. Remove my original myname@my-azure-ad from the DevOps org
4. Re-add myname@my-azure-ad to the org and re-assign as the owner

The only thing I can conclude is that because myname@my-azure-ad was originally added to the org before the org was linked to the AAD that this must have messed something up.